# MailChimp error with popup when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, mailchimp

I'm trying to add a popup form from mailchimp to my website but I keep getting this error although I copy pasted it from their website.

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.dojoRequire is not a function
    at showMailingPopUp (index.html:39)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:116)
```

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script>
function showMailingPopUp() {
document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us4.list-manage.com","uuid":"fd5cf79a3e9cee3f451200e01","lid":"ce87ac273d","uniqueMethods":true}) })
};

    </script>
<input type="button" class="subscribe-button" id="open-popup" onClick="showMailingPopUp()" value="Subscribe">
```